# Compiling scala successful but not running it

Tags: scala

I know i can use sbt to avoid all this problem but just for knowledge sake. I am not sure why i can compile the code but not able to run it.

My directory structure is as such:

```
$ ls io_monad/*
io_monad/Test.scala

io_monad/classes:
io_monad

io_monad/lib:
cats-core_2.12-0.9.0.jar cats-effect_2.12-0.7.jar
```

Simple Test.scala file

```
package io_monad

import cats.effect.IO

object Test extends App {

    val program:IO[Unit] = for {
        _         <- IO { println("First name?") }
        firstName <- IO { scala.io.StdIn.readLine }
        _         <- IO { println(s"Last name?") }
        lastName  <- IO { scala.io.StdIn.readLine }
        _         <- IO { println(s"First: $firstName, Last: $lastName") }
    } yield ()

    program.unsafeRunSync()
}
```

Compiling successful

```
$ scalac -cp "io_monad/lib/cats-core_2.12-0.9.0.jar:io_monad/lib/cats-effect_2.12-0.7.jar" -d io_monad/classes io_monad/Test.scala
```

But not the running of app

```
$ scala -cp "io_monad/lib/cats-core_2.12-0.9.0.jar:io_monad/lib/cats-effect_2.12-0.7.jar:io_monad/classes/" io_monad.Test
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cats.kernel.Semigroup
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At compile time your code only depends on the class files in those 2 jars on your classpath, but at runtime the code in `cats-core` or `cats-effect` also requires classes from `cats-kernel`. This isn't a problem during compilation because the code that depends on `cats-kernel` is already compiled to bytecode.

Comment: Can you help to see if i understood this correctly.

I found out that during compilation only `cat-effect` is needed. During runtime `cats-core and cats-kernel` is needed as well.

So i assume during compilation and creation of `cats-effect`, `cats-kernel` and `cats-core` jar files were in the classpath. Hence `cats-effect` is able to compile successfully and jar created. Hence during runtime those 2 jar files need to be present in the classpath as well.